# What does "SomeName => {}" mean?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react coming from a .Net background and I was trying to create a class, I tried numerous ways of doing so but in this instance I was unable to create a constructor in this variation and came to the conclusion that this maybe isn't a class, I've searched around the web but haven't found any info

Here is an example:

```
   export default ViewTestStuff => {

     constructor(){
       // errors
       }
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

so my question is what is the "=> {}" in this example, is this a class? and why can't I create a constructor in it if it is indeed a class

Comment: It's a syntactically-invalid attempt to create a stateless function. Which is just that--a function. Basic JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Now it's even more syntactically-invalid. You seem to just be making stuff up. MCDP (Markov Chain Driven Programming) almost never works.

Comment: Ah I see, Thanks a lot. Thats the point I was making. I'm new to it so I was getting a feel for the syntax and the different things it can do whilst using the react documentation

Comment: It'll make more sense if you learn some JS first, at least the basics, otherwise the React docs will be illegible.

Comment: I do have some js knowledge, I just haven't kept up with the recent additions to es6, hence my new venture and realisation I need to do some back tracking

Comment: I think this `export default ViewTestStuff => { }` is ES6 short hand for this `export default ViewTestStuff = () => {}`

Comment: @jmb.mage I disagree; I think it would export a function with a parameter named `ViewTestStuff`.

Comment: @DaveNewton so it's short hand for 'export default class { }' ?  A class is what is exported?

Comment: @jmb.mage No, a function is exported, because it's a function. An arrow function does not require parens around a single parameter, but if there are no parens, the token before the `=>` will be parsed as the single parameter to that arrow function. You can try this at babeljs.io/repl and look at the transpiled code, although Murilo's answer states the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Arrow Function from es6, and has nothing to do with React.js

```
const add = (a, b) => a+b;
```

it is just a function.

calling `add(2, 3)` returns `5`

One important thing to remember is, that arrow functions do not have the prototype chain. You also cannot call them with `new`.

Another thing to notice is, that `this` is bound to the context where the arrow function is defined.

```js
const obj = {
    name: "Lukas",
    method: function() {
        var self = this;
        console.log(this.name === "Lukas");
        return [
          function() {
              console.log(this !== self)
          }, 
          () => {
              console.log(this === self)
          }
        ];
    }
}

const [func, arrow] = obj.method();

func();
arrow();
```

[see the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks for this descriptive answer, makes a lot more sense. Pardon my lack of js knowledge, seems like it was quite obvious

Answer (score 1):

It is an arrow function! A nice feature on ES6, that is already implemented on most modern browsers.

`Something => {}` Means a function with Something as it's parameter and an empty body. It is similar to:

```
function (Something) {
}
```

In your case, it's the same as:

```
export default function (ViewTestStuff) {

 constructor(){
   // errors
   }
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And it's indeed invalid.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that would be invalid. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not a React thing... arrow functions are new in es6 javascript. More info can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions